# Migration from WAMP to LAMP

Tags: php, web-hosting

I pretend to develop my website on a WAMP Stack on my local pc and then when it's finished, to migrate the website to some Company's Host Server running a LAMP Stack.
I have two questions :
1 - Will it be trivial ( only minor changes necessary) to migrate by website developed on WAMP Stack to the host running the LAMP ?
2 - Do i need to know Linux in order to administrate and setup my website on some Company's Host Server running it under LAMP ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There are too many combination possible. But, since u developed it on wamp, I am guessing it is a simple matter of dropping all the files into the www folder, as suggested below. For more complex sites, that would not hold though

Comment: This question is real broad one - it depends on LAMP component versions/configuration you are using, project scale, what are your duties as admin, etc.

Answer (score 2):

1) The default public directory in WAMP is `www` while in LAMP it is `public_html`. So you can upload the files in the same directory structure but under public_html. In some cases, `www` is also present in both, so make sure you check that.

2) It depends on the server software. If you have a hosting control panel installed like `Cpanel`, `Virtualmin` etc., you can upload the files and database through the GUI interface otherwise you can learn the linux commands which are very basic and use the `SSH`. Alternatively you can make use of the FTP as well through `FileZilla` or `WinSCP` to upload the files.